# Android 4.4.2 and File Observer - create file recognition

Tags: android, file, sony

I have problem with recognition of file creation on tablet Sony Xperia Z with android 4.4.2 I have code like this:

```
private void observeDirectory(final String path){
        observer = new FileObserver(path) { // set up a file observer to watch this directory on sd card


            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, String file) {

                //Log.v("FILE EVENT", "Event id: " + Integer.toString(event));
                switch (event) {
                    case FileObserver.ACCESS:
                        //Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE ACCESS " + file);
                    break;

                    case FileObserver.OPEN:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE Open: " + file);
                    break;

                    case  android.os.FileObserver.MOVED_FROM:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE Moved From: " + file);
                    break;

                    case  android.os.FileObserver.MOVED_TO:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE Moved to: " + file);
                    break;

                    case  android.os.FileObserver.MOVE_SELF:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE Moved self: " + file);
                    break;

                    case FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE closed & no - write: " + file);
                    break;

                    case FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE closed & write: " + file);
                    break;

                    case  android.os.FileObserver.MODIFY:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE closed & no - write: " + file);
                    break;

                    case  android.os.FileObserver.CREATE:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "File created [" + path + "/" + file + "]");
                    break;
                    case FileObserver.DELETE:
                        Log.d("FILE OBSERVER", "FILE DELETED " + file);
                    break;


                }



            }

        };
        observer.startWatching(); //START OBSERVING
    }
```

And it is working but not giving me info about all activities. As a parameter to this method I'm passing folder path. I have info about accessing the file, opening ans closing without save. But I have also different android app which creates files in this directory. I have to detect when it happens using file observer but I can't make it work. I don't need to use recurrence there because I have only one folder with files. How can I make it work?

The funny thing is that, this code works like a charm on Samsung devices and on Nexus 5 (kitkat / Android L) and Nexus7 (kitkat). But somehow there is problem with Xperia Tablet Z and I really don't know why is it like so. I see alerts about accessing file only on applikation start when it is loading files into a listview. But after that totally nothinhg. On Nexus I have it working all the time, I have got info about creating and writing file. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get FileObserver to work on the KitKat only by adding uses-permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the manifest. I don't know why this permission became necessary from 4.4 version of Android, and probably it is needed only if you're going to monitor external storage. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation or information about this behaviour change.

You're probably trying to watch internal storage, as you were able (unlike me) to bring it working on the Nexus 7, but this answer still could be useful for somebody.